# Why does <input> sometimes include "id" and "name" & sometimes neither but producing the same visual output?

Tags: html, forms, input, tags, label

Method 1, ex. 1:

```
<form>
      <label for="name"> Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" />
</form>
```

Method 1, ex. 2:

```
 <form>
            <label for="name">First name:</label>
            <input id="lfname" name="fname" type="text">
        </form>
```

—> Both structures look the same in browser. Both inputs include input id and + input type (in different chronological order, I guess that does not matter when using attributes?) - but: why does the 2nd also include name= again, if it looks the same on the browser anyway?

Method 2, ex. 1:

```
<form>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" />
      </label>
</form>
```

Method 2, ex. 2:

```
 <form>
      <label>Name
        <input id="User" name="Name" type="text" />
      </label>
    </form>
```

—> Both structures look the same in browser. Here: In the 2nd, input id and name is used & in the 1st example both are left out and only type specified. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `name` is used for many purposes in PHP it is used to get the data of the input tag and many more.

The attribute `id` is also used for many purposes like in javascript you get the by using `document.getElementById` and many more

Answer (score 1):

name in an input element is used for backend purposes and ID too but in most cases you as a frontend dev will find yourself using it in CSS and JAVASCRIPT as well.